# Even the Copy Assignment Operator can't assist

Tags: c++

Kindly help me figure out where the issue is. I have followed the rule of three as well and made several modifications to the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AStack {
    public:
        AStack();
        AStack(int);
        AStack(const AStack&);
        ~AStack();
        AStack& operator = (const AStack& s);
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty();
        void flush();

    private:
        int capacity ;
        int* a;
        int index = -1; // Index of the top most element
};

AStack::AStack() {
    a = new int[25];
    capacity = 25;
}

AStack::AStack(int size) {
    a = new int[size];
    capacity = size;
}

AStack::AStack(const AStack& s) {
    capacity = s.capacity;
    delete[] a; // To avoid memory leak
    a = new int[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) { 
        a[i] = s.a[i];
    }
    index = s.index;
}

AStack::~AStack() {
    delete[] a;
}

AStack& AStack::operator = (const AStack& s) {
    capacity = s.capacity;
    delete[] a; // To avoid memory leak
    int* a = new int[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        a[i] = s.a[i];
    }
    index = s.index;
    return *this;
}

void AStack::push(int x) {
    if (index == capacity - 1) {
        cout << "\n\nThe stack is full. Couldn't insert " << x << "\n\n";
        return;
    }
    a[++index] = x;
}

int AStack::pop() {
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements to pop\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    return a[index--];
}

int AStack::top() {
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    return a[index];
}

bool AStack::isEmpty() {
    return (index == -1);
}

void AStack::flush() {
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack to flush\n\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\nFlushing the Stack:  ";
    while (index != -1) {
        cout << a[index--] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

AStack& reverseStack(AStack& s1) {
    AStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
    return s1;
}

int main() {

    AStack s1;
    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(2);
    s1.push(3);
    s1.push(4);
    s1.push(5);
    s1 = reverseStack(s1);
    cout << "\n\nFlushing s1:\n";
    s1.flush();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**I fail to understand how even after defining the appropriate copy assignment operator, the values in s1 after returning from the function are garbage values.**

Comment: In the copy-constructor you call `delete[] a;` but `a` has not been assigned yet. This causes UB. The comment `// To avoid memory leak` is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

If your copy constructor is correct, and your destructor is correct, your assignment operator could be written in a *much* easier and safer fashion.

Currently, your assignment operator has two major flaws:

1. No check for self-assignment.
2. Changing the state of `this` before you know you can successfully allocate the 
   memory (your code is not exception safe).

The reason for your error is that the call to `reverseStack` returns a reference to the current object.  This invoked the assignment operator, thus your assignment operator was assigning the current object to the current object.  Thus issue `1` above gets triggered.

You delete yourself, and then you reallocate yourself, but where did you get the values from in the loop to assign?  They were deleted, thus they're garbage.

For item `2` above, these lines change `this` before you allocate memory:

```
capacity = s.capacity;
delete[] a; // To avoid memory leak
```

What happens if the call to `new[]` throws an exception?  You've messed up your object by not only changing the capacity value, but you've also destroyed your data in the object by calling `delete[]` prematurely.

The other issue (which needs to be fixed to use the copy/swap idiom later in the answer), is that your copy constructor is deallocating memory it never allocated:

```
AStack::AStack(const AStack& s) {
    capacity = s.capacity;
    delete[] a;  // ??  What
```

Remove the line with the `delete[] a`, since you are more than likely calling `delete[]` on a pointer that's pointing to garbage.

Now, to rid you of these issues with the assignment operator, the copy/swap idiom should be used.  This requires a *working* copy constructor and a *working* destructor before you can utilize this method.  That's why we needed to fix your copy constructor first before proceeding.

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
AStack& AStack::operator = (AStack s) 
{
    std::swap(capacity, s.capacity);
    std::swap(a, s.a);
    std::swap(index, s.index);
    return *this;
}
```

Note that we do not need to check for self assignment, as the object that is passed by value is a brand new, temporary object that we are taking the values from, and never the current object's values (again, this is the reason for your original code to fail).

Also, if `new[]` threw an exception, it would have been thrown on the call to the assignment operator when creating the temporary object that is passed by value.  Thus we never get the chance to inadvertently mess up our object because of `new[]` throwing an exception.

Please read up on what the `copy/swap` idiom is, and why this is the easiest, safest, and robust way to write an assignment operator.  This answer explains in detail what you need to know:

[What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Here is a live example of the fixed code.  Note that there are other changes, such as removing the default constructor and making the `Attack(int)` destructor take a default parameter of 25.

Live Example: http://ideone.com/KbA20D

Comment: Thank you buddy, but can you please answer my question that is in bold? Why does it print garbage values?

Comment: @KW123 It's irrelevant what it prints, since your copy constructor has undefined behavior.  You are calling `delete[]` on an uninitialized pointer -- you were lucky just to not have the program crash right there.

Comment: @KW123 `I fail to understand how even after defining the appropriate copy assignment operator,`  First, it was not "appropriate" as it had two flaws that I pointed out.

Comment: @KW123 As to the reason for the garbage values, look at my answer with respect to the assignment operator and issue `1`.  You failed to check for the self assignment, so your `Attack` object was deleting itself.